# How to change objects inside of vectors globally c++

Tags: c++

When an object is placed inside a vector, the vector makes a copy of the object, this means that any changes to the object does not change the object inside the vector. How do i make so any changes to the object also change the object inside the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class objectClass {
public:
    int x = 0;
};

vector<int> my_vector;


int main()
{
    objectClass testObject;
    vector<objectClass> my_vector = {testObject};
    testObject.x = 5;
    cout << my_vector[0].x;
}

//outputs 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two way

1. change the object from the vector like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class objectClass {
public:
    int x = 0;
};

vector<int> my_vector;


int main()
{
    objectClass testObject;
    
    vector<objectClass> my_vector = {testObject};
    
    my_vector[0].x = 5;
    
    cout << my_vector[0].x;
}
```

2. or you can do this by using pointers or reference, use a vector of pointers, where the vector will have the collections of objects references and thus changing the object from outside the vector also will change from inside the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class objectClass {
public:
    int x = 0;
};

int main()
{
    objectClass testObject;
    vector<objectClass*> my_vector = {&testObject};
    testObject.x = 5;
    cout << my_vector[0]->x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be having a vector of pointers instead, where each pointer points to some instance of `objectClass`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class objectClass {
public:
    int x = 0;
};

int main()
{
    objectClass testObject;
    vector<objectClass*> my_vector = {&testObject};
    testObject.x = 5;
    cout << my_vector[0]->x;
}
```